# SuiteCRM email encryption

Tags: php, email, encryption, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I installed `SuiteCRM` on my server. All the things work very well, but something is problematic for me; emails are not encrypted.

After some searching, I successfully enabled the `encrypt` field type (https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/pull/1756)

But the email field are not an ordinary field, it's more a list than input field.
I have tried to find email field definition in the code and I have replaced `varchar` with `encrypt` and cleared cache... But it still doesn't work...

How should I go about properly changing the original email field to enable encryption?

Comment: This has been added to the SuiteCRM trello board: https://trello.com/c/kWf3szIG

Answer (score 1):

Email encryption is not a built-in feature, but you can add it by implementing it in the proper hooks in the email module.

You would put the encryption logic in the `before_save` and the decryption logic in the `after_retrieve` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Oups ,

The EmailAddresses modules is not a full function bean module (https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/30127-hook-to-optout-e-mail-in-module-contacts)

So i must do the encryption in contact module logic hooks. But for the decryption, i will must create a logichooks for every module who will use email :(

Comment: I am not what you mean by fully functioning. The email module inherits from the sugar bean which has the usual save and retrieve methods. When you said encrypting the emails. I am assuming you are referring to the group / personal emails feature. Am I right? Is that what you meant?

Comment: When you add a contact into Suite CRM, you can add one or more email address in relation with this contact. The emails are saved in `email_addresses` database and a relation are create with the contact. What i'm trying to do is crypt the email address in the `email_addresses` database. So i can use the contact logichook for crypt but if i want to decrypt in all module that uses the e-mail address, i must change all the logichooks. I thought that all the 'email adress' read and write was centralized in the EmailAdresses modules and i could use the EmailAddresses module logichook...

Comment: I hope to be clear, if it's not... it's not my fault i am french ;-)

Comment: No problem. It's still a good idea to encrypt contents in the database. Thanks for clarifying :D